# python : json.loads()[str] returns a string

Tags: python, json, string, twitter

I am trying to tokenize a tweet using regex. Here tokens_re and emoticon_re are 2 regex objects

```
def tokenize(s):
    return tokens_re.findall(s)

def preprocess(s, lowercase=False):
    tokens = tokenize(s)
    if lowercase:
        tokens = [token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower() for token in tokens]
    return tokens

with open('twitterdata.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
```

`s` must be a string here but how is `tweet['text']` a string?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a string?

Comment: `json.loads()` doesnt return a string I am not aware of the syntax really what does`['text]' do?

Comment: It's an indexing operator.

Comment: so it returns corresponding to the key `text` in the dict returned by `json.loads()`?

Comment: @kartikeykant18 Yes. That's how dictionaries work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not actually using the index here correctly. It could have been better if you could provide a sample of the JSON data.
Anyway, you can try this.

**tokens = preprocess(tweet[0]['text'])**

here 0 is the first index.
You can put this in a loop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What makes you think `tweet` is a list?

Comment: I am getting the output:



"""
{  
    "hashtags":[  
        {  
            "text":"snow",
            "indices":[  
                66,
                71
            ]
        },
        {  
            "text":"skiing",
            "indices":[  
                73,
                80
            ]
        }
    ]
}"""
      
        
        
        
        
import json
str = ""
with open  ('data.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        str+= line
tweet = json.loads(str)
print tweet['hashtags'][0]['text']


Let me know if I am wrong